# Windows phone Textblock not showing large text

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

How to show large text string in windows phone using `textblock` or `richtextbox` ?
currently I am facing issue to show large amount of text in `textbox` its truncated

Comment: What style have you applied?

Comment: the problem is when more than 500 characters its not showing properly

Comment: That bind would only ever show the date? Perhaps you could edit your question to include the XAML and a screenshot of it truncating?

Comment: <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="28" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding message}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="Auto"><!--320-->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue we created a converter. So to start we should place a ContentPresenter on the page instead of TextBlock in order to display content we like

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding BodyText,Converter={StaticResource LongTextConverter}}" />

public string BodyText
```

{
    get
    {
        return "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...";
    }
}

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        UIElement result = null;

        if (value != null)
        {
            string data = value.ToString();

            if (data.Length <= MinLength)
            {
                result = new TextBlock
                             {
                                 Text = data,
                                 Style = App.Current.Resources["ArticleBodyStyle"] as Style,
                                 HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
                             };
            }
            else
            {
                StackPanel resultPanel = new StackPanel();
                int min = 0;
                int max = MinLength;
                while (true)
                {
                    string temp = data.Substring(min, max - min);
                    if (max != data.Length)
                    {
                        int index = temp.LastIndexOf('\n');
                        index = index == -1 ? temp.LastIndexOf('.') + 1 : -1;
                        max = (index == -1) ? max : index;
                        temp = data.Substring(min, max) + '\n';
                        resultPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock
                                                     {
                                                         Margin = new Thickness(12, 0, 12, -30),
                                                         Text = temp,
                                                         Style = App.Current.Resources["ArticleBodyStyle"] as Style,
                                                         HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
                                                     });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        resultPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock
                                                     {
                                                         Margin = new Thickness(12, 0, 12, 0),
                                                         Text = temp,
                                                         Style = App.Current.Resources["ArticleBodyStyle"] as Style,
                                                         HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
                                                     });
                        break;
                    }

                    min += max;
                    max = min + MinLength;
                    if (max > data.Length)
                    {
                        max = data.Length;
                    }
                }

                result = resultPanel;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Phone there is a constraint on the size of any single control such that it avoids the creation of very large surfaces needing to be drawn and that would definitely impact performance.

There are various approaches to solving this and there's an example of a work around that automatically takes text and breaks it up over multiple TextBlocks at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx

If you have a more specific example and repro please update your question with this.